# How to get the last child of each cd element?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd country="USA">
        <disk>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <price>10.90</price>
        </disk>
        <disk>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <price>9.90</price>
        </disk>
        <disk>
            <title>KDGFJDLF</title>
            <artist>mnxc  lxck</artist>
            <price>7.20</price>
        </disk>
    </cd>
    <cd country="USA">
        <disk>
            <title>Greatest Hits</title>
            <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
            <price>12.90</price>
        </disk>
        <disk>
            <title>ASD</title>
            <artist>abc def</artist>
            <price>12.30</price>
        </disk>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I need to get the last child and 2nd last child of each cd (price).

So the result of the 1st CD is: 
last child (disk 3): 7.20
& 2nd last child (disk 2): 9.90

the result of the 2nd CD is: 
last child (disk 2): 12.30
& 2nd last child (disk 1): 12.90

only need the price

I can get the prices of one of the cd but iam clueless to get the prices of every cd (if new ones are added).

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load(realpath('cd.xml'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$asd = $xml ->getElementsByTagName( "cd" ); 
$qwe = $xpath ->query('//catalog/cd');

foreach ($qwe as $qwe) {
$lastPrice = $xpath->query('//catalog/cd /disk[last()]/price')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$secondLastPrice = $xPath->query('//catalog/cd /disk[last()-1]/price')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

How do i continue from $qwe. to get the last price and 2nd last price of each cd?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an xpath expression, which selects the last two elements from cd and returns them. If you just want the price, you could also append that.

```
//catalog/cd/disk[position()>last()-2]/price
```

Comment: If catalog contains something different, theire might be an xml design issue. Nevertheless, each disk should have the same tag

Comment: inside the foreach ($qwe as $qwe) loop i made another for each loop which prints the last price but how do i get the 2nd last price now lol.
$lastP = $xPath->query('//customerInfos/customer/meter/meterDate[last()]');
 foreach ($lastP as $n) {
        $lastPrice = $n->nodeValue;
}

Comment: @Marvelo instead of `[last()]` you should use `[position()>last()-2]` - this gives you the last two elememts

Comment: @Philipp sorry i just fixed the xml

Comment: @Philipp i need those 2 values in 2 variables. would another for loop work?

Answer (score 0):

Gets prices of all nodes in `cd` that start with `disk` with `last` and `last -1` positions

```
//cd/*[starts-with(name(),'disk')][position() > last()-2]/price
```

or if you need to keep catalog:

```
//catalog/cd/*[starts-with(name(),'disk')][position() > last()-2]/price
```